# android weightSum not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with three elements and its orientation is 'horizontal'

I want to fix the size that each element occupy in my layout.

first element should take 40% of the total space then second element should occupy 5% and third one should occupy remaining 55% space.

My layout look like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outletname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:text="@string/outlet_name2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text=": " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outletnamevalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="55"
        android:text="abcdefttt" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

text in 'TextView' will change dynamically , So I want to keep the constant space for elements irrespective of the content in views...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In order to make **weight** effective, you must also need to set the *widths* of your *TextViews* to *0dp*.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: to complete the answer, one must understand that the weight only applies to /remaining/ space, i.e. space left once the layout_width value was applied.

Comment: this made my day :D for how many years... LOL . so that's the only answer on the problem . UPVOTEEEEEEE

Comment: \o/ i love youuuuuuuuuuuuu... thank thank thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

I use this formula:

```
layout_weight=(weightSum-PercentageYouWant*weightSum)/(TotalElements-1)
```

> first element should take 40% of the total space then second element should occupy 5% and third one should occupy remaining 55% space.

1st Element:

```
(100-0.4*100)/(3-1)="30"
```

2nd Element:

```
(100-0.05*100)/(3-1)="47.5"
```

3rd Element:

```
(100-0.55*100)/(3-1)="22.5"
```

so `40% + 5% + 55% = 100%`

```
layout_weight="30" + layout_weight="47.5" + layout_weight="22.5" = weightSum="100"
```

that's how I understand it.

here's an example (buttons are just for graphic reference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="120" >

    <!-- WeightSum=120 and I will add 4 elements, so TotalElements=4 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="36"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- I want this LinearLayout to be 10%, so (120-10%*120)/(4-1)=36 -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="10%" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="32"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- I want this LinearLayout to be 20%, so (120-20%*120)/(4-1)=32 -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="20%" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="28"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- I want this LinearLayout to be 30%, so (120-30%*120)/(4-1)=28 -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="30%" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="24"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- I want this LinearLayout to be 40%, so (120-40%*120)/(4-1)=24 -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="40%" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```